# AngularJS UI router: How to configure nested named views?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a configuration like below:

```
...
.state('profiles', {
    abstract: true
    , url : '/profiles'
    , resolve: {...}    
    , views: {
      mainModule: {
        templateUrl : '/partials/home.html'
        , controller : 'HomeCtrl'
      }
      , leftSidePaneModule: {
          templateUrl : '/partials/leftSidePane.html'
          , controller : 'LeftSidePaneCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
...
```

**Main Jade File**

```
...
.col-xs-4.col-md-4.chat_block(ui-view='leftSidePaneModule', autoscroll="false")  
...
```

So, `leftSidePaneModule` module gets populated in to `ui-view='leftSidePaneModule'` placeholder. But the problem is, I have 2 more named views inside `leftSidePaneModule` template. `leftSidePaneModule` template looks like this:

**leftSidePaneModule.html**

```
<div>
  <div ui-view="leftWidgetOne"></div>
  <div ui-view="leftWidgetTwo"></div>
</div>
```

How do i make modules `leftWidgetOne` & `leftWidgetOne` gets populated in to above placeholder?

I tried,

```
...
.state('profiles', {
    abstract: true
    , url : '/profiles'
    , resolve: {...}    
    , views: {
      mainModule: {
        templateUrl : '/partials/home.html'
        , controller : 'HomeCtrl'
      }
      , leftSidePaneModule: {
          templateUrl : '/partials/leftSidePane.html'
          , controller : 'LeftSidePaneCtrl'
      }
      , 'leftWidgetOne@leftSidePaneModule' : {...}
      , 'leftWidgetTwo@leftSidePaneModule' : {...}
    }
  })
...
```

Attempt: 2

```
...
.state('profiles', {
    abstract: true
    , url : '/profiles'
    , resolve: {...}    
    , views: {
      mainModule: {
        templateUrl : '/partials/home.html'
        , controller : 'HomeCtrl'
      }
      , leftSidePaneModule: {
          templateUrl : '/partials/leftSidePane.html'
          , controller : 'LeftSidePaneCtrl'
          , views: {
             'leftWidgetOne' : {...}
             , 'leftWidgetTwo' : {...}
          }
      }
    }
  })
...
```

Both are not working.

How do you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you along: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863663/angularjs-complex-nesting-of-partials-and-templates

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The solution could be found here: [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names). A cite:

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of `viewname@statename`, where `viewname` is the name used in the `view` directive and **state name** is the state's absolute name, e.g. `contact.item`
>   ...
>   *(note: in our case it must be `'profiles'`)*.

The point is, that we can use the full *(absolute)* name of the `view`, being part of the **current** state definition:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('profiles', {
        url: '/profiles',
        views: {
            mainModule: {
                template: '<div>' +
                          '  <h1>Main</h1>' +
                          '  <div ui-view="leftSidePaneModule"></div>' +
                          '</div>',
            },
            // here we do target the view just added above, as a 'mainModule'
            // as <div ui-view="leftSidePaneModule">
            'leftSidePaneModule@profiles': {
                template: '<div>' + 
                            '  <div ui-view="leftWidgetOne"></div>' + 
                            '  <div ui-view="leftWidgetTwo"></div>' +
                            '</div>',
            },
            // and here we do target the sub view
            // but still part of the state 'profiles' defined in the above
            // view defintion 'leftSidePaneModule@profiles'
            'leftWidgetOne@profiles': {
                template: '<h2>One</2>',
            },
            'leftWidgetTwo@profiles': {
                template: '<h2>Two</2>',
            },
        }
    });
```

There is also [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/duv8MKfK18DpW6KlfqKl?p=preview) showing the above code in action

Comment: Seriously, THANK YOU for explaining this. I can't tell you how long I spent trying to figure this out.

Comment: this needs to be upvoted so many more times than it is. I was searching forever to find this.

Comment: I also searched forever for this, this was extremely helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks a lot for this, I couldn't make it work, I tried several hours without success

Comment: Funny that the docs state something similar but this made more sense to me. Thanks for explaining this.

Comment: Can we use profiles as abstract state ? I need to create nested stated with this like profiles.xyz

Comment: Hi nice answer! Quick question, how would you load another state into one of those named views? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956873/angularjs-ui-router-how-to-load-a-state-view-into-another-nested-view-of-a-top-l